# IPv4 timing out on certain sites

Tags: networking, ipv4

I study Computer Science and for some coursework this year we investigated pinging different websites with different protocols. One of the questions concerns pinging Netflix and eBay with IPv4 - specifically it asks if we notice anything. When pinging these two specific websites, the request times out. I assume this is what I'm supposed to notice, but I'm not sure why. I have been thinking that either it's for security reasons or neither of these sites uses IPv4. Am I correct?

I tried to route Netflix and this happened:
[image]

It's clear that it starts to time out after the 9th hop. Any ideas why?

Comment: What happens if you ping them with IPv6?

Comment: Hosts can be configured not to respond to ICMP echo requests, and ICMP echo requests or replies can be blocked anywhere in the path.

Comment: You should read [Should I block ICMP?](http://shouldiblockicmp.com/)

Comment: @DavidPostill When I tried to ping Netflix with IPv6 worked perfectly fine, but for ebay it gave me an error that it could not find the host.